# ASP.NET , LoginDataContext does not contain a definition for profiles

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Profile table but profiles is in red and gives me an error that 'LoginDataContext' does not contain a definition for 'profiles'

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace practice
    {
        public partial class LoginDataContext
        {
            public Profile get_profileid(int id)
            {
                return this.profiles.SingleOrDefault(p => p.profile_id == id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: return this.profiles.SingleOrDefault(p => p.profile_id == id);  gives me an error

Comment: You need to check other partial part of `LoginDataContext` class to see if there is `profiles` property in it.

Comment: Since it's a partial class provide the other partial if possible.